# Не совсем понятно, почему ответ именно такой

Tags: java

Итак есть программа, которая выводит следующее:

> 13 15 x = 6

Но не совсем понятно почему x = 6, а не 7 (как мне казалось должно выйти) и почему значение y выводит после 13 не 14, а сразу 15

```
public class Output {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Output o = new Output();
        o.go();
}

void go() {
    int y = 7;
    for (int x = 1; x < 8; x++) {
        y++;
        if (x > 4) {
            System.out.print(++y + " ");
        }
        if (y > 14) {
            System.out.println(" x = " + x);
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

P.S. Объясните, как программа ведет себя после того как x доходит до значение равное 5

Comment: потому что вы дважды инкрементируете y в цикле

Comment: Ну да это понятно, но вот логика не совсем ясна. Почему x = 6, а не 7? Почему y равняется сначала 13, а потом тут же 15, куда исчезает 14

Comment: @АлексейШавкунов, воспользуйтесь отладчиком и посмотрите своими глазами как изменяются переменные при проходе по каждой строчке. Это будет намного наглядней, и быстрей, чем ждать когда вам всё разжуют здесь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Почему 13 и потом сразу 15?

Когда первый раз (`x = 5`) выполняется условие `x > 4`, в этот момент постфиксный инкремент `y++` дает 12, а префиксный инкремент в `System.out.print(++y + " ");` дает `y = 13`. Вторая итерация, когда `x = 6`, опять же срабатывают два инкремента и на выходе получаем `y = 15`.

> Почему x = 6, а не 7?

Когда выполняется условие `y > 14`, в этот момент `x = 6`, в теле условия это выводится на печать и `break` заканчивает работу цикла `for`, поэтому `x` не достигает значения 7.